# T-Sql Equivalent of Authorization and Grand for a function in Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

We have a function that is written in t-sql and we converted it for oracle. But I cannot find equivalent of Authorization keyword for oracle.

```
GO

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON [DOCSADM].[Cbinary] TO  SCHEMA OWNER 
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON [DOCSADM].[Cbinary] TO [public] AS [DOCSADM]
GO
```

DOCSAdm is a user and CBinary is myfunction name. How to convert these sql code for oracle?

Answer (score 1):

The `ALTER AUTHORIZATION` transfers ownership of an object to another user.
As Oracle handles Users and Schemas a bit differently than SQL Server, there is no equivalent. In general, an object like your function `Cbinary` is owned by the schema it is located in.

Moving an object to another user/schema in Oracle is done in the way that you use the `CREATE`-Script like you would use it normally, but just add the new schema-name in front of the object-name, like this:

```
create function newschema.cbinary return varchar2 as
    begin
        -- your code here
    end cbinary;
```